# Git Workflow - "untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout"

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, git

thanks in advance for taking your time to help me and others that may be stuck at the same point.

I've installed Magento on my machine, created .gitignore following documentation, made change on a file, made a commit, and pushed to my repo. 
On other machine I installed Magento, and pulled the repo according to the [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/deployment/pipeline/technical-details.html), but I get an error when pulling the repo:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout
```

I think this is happening because this process is not really the right one. Where I'm getting it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this: fetch all files and reset to master branch. But I think this isn't the best way to work. Must have some other way.

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```